# vlc mac python bindings video output and location of vlc.py

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, vlc

I am hoping that someone can help with a Python bindings output question (using vlc.py)

I have a basic test script that uses vlc.py which runs but does not play the video.

```
import vlc

def setup_player(filename):
    vlc_instance = vlc.Instance('--no-audio', '--fullscreen')
    player = vlc_instance.media_player_new()
    media = vlc_instance.media_new(filename)
    player.set_media(media)
    print media.get_mrl() # File location to get title 
    print player.get_length() #Time duration of file -1 means there is no   media
    print player.get_state() #Player's state
    player.play()

setup_player('foo.mp4')
```

This outputs

```
file:///Users/admin/Sites/pythontest/foo.mp4
-1
State.NothingSpecial
```

I am unsure where to install the vlc.py module and hoping someone can help. I'm on MacOs, VLC 2.0.9, Python 2.7.3. Running python through the terminal.

At the moment I have the vlc.py module in the same directory as my test script - and outside of the VLC.app directories and although the script is executing without errors it isn't playing the video or returning any parameters about the specified mp4 file.

Apologies for a banal question! Any help very gratefully received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the `player.play()` function is not blocking, but instead returns immediately.

If the Python script then terminates, the player is destroyed right after it has been created.

If you look at the [example player in `vlc.py`](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob;f=generated/vlc.py;h=050200f8d3771392c4dc2bdf514dad0e100512e5;hb=HEAD#l6855), it has a `while True` loop at the very end that basically reads key presses over and over again in order to implement a simple user interface.

So if you simply add

```
while True:
    pass
```

at the end of your function, it should continue playing (terminate with <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> until you implement some sort of user input handling).

As for "installing" the script: Unfortunately, the `vlc.py` module they provide is just that, a simple stand-alone Python module. It's not packaged as a setuptools distribution that you could just install with `pip` or `easy_install` like most other Python modules. That means you can (or rather have to) drop it into a location that will be in `sys.path` yourself.

The current working directory where you launch your script from works for that, but if you want a more permanent location you could drop it into your Python's `site-packages` (`/Users/<your-username>/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages` for example if you're using the standard OS X framework Python).

Comment: Thanks for the advice about the installation of vlc.py. Using a `while True:` loop forced the video file to attempt to play, but it outputted a `corrupt module: .. VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/../plugins/libmacosx_plugin.dylib` , so I am reinstalling vlc.

Comment: It seems that to simply test the vlc.py module you can use its built in player with `$ python vlc.py /path/to/file.mp4` usefully documented [here](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=100547#p340428)

Comment: @rod exactly - that's where I assumed you based your script on actually :)

Comment: @rod I get the same thing here - corrupt libraries, even though VLC itself is working fine (VLC 2.1.4, OS X 10.9.5). Video playback using the Python bindings currently doesn't work for me, audio works fine though.

Comment: re-installing vlc hasn't worked and it seems vlc.py hasn't been built for  64 bit architecture as per [this](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=104906#p355522) post.

Comment: I have run the same lipo commands which return `Architectures in the fat file: /usr/bin/python are: i386 x86_64` and `Non-fat file:/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/plugins/libmacosx_plugin.dylib is architecture: x86_64' as per the post linked above - so this seems to be the problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the API calls succeed, it means that the bindings work correctly. The problem here is rather that the macos x video output module is not able to instanciate its own window. It *must* be embedded in a native Cocoa widget.
You can use the [qt example](https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/tree/master/examples) from the vlc repository or use the x11 video output module, combined with the MacOS X X11 server (which has to be installed for recent versions of MacOS X).